# localstack k8s deployment yaml and health check endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, localstack

I've set up win 10, minikube, docker.
I need to start localstack in my local minikube. I didn't find out k8s deployment yaml. So I take docker compose yaml that provided by them at github. And create file like below:

```
# disk volume claim
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    com.job.service: localstack-claim0
  name: localstack-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
---
# service account
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: localstack-account
  labels:
    com.job.service: localstack-service-account
---
# service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    com.job.service: localstack-service
  name: localstack-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - name: "edge"
      port: 4566
      targetPort: 4566
    - name: "es"
      port: 4571
      targetPort: 4571
    - name: "ui"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    com.job.service: localstack-service
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
# deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    com.job.service: localstack-deployment
  name: localstack-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      com.job.service: localstack-deployment
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        com.job.service: localstack-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: DATA_DIR
              value: ' '
            - name: DEBUG
              value: ' '
            - name: DOCKER_HOST
              value: tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
            - name: HOST_TMP_FOLDER
            - name: KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY
              value: ' '
            - name: LAMBDA_EXECUTOR
              value: ' '
            - name: PORT_WEB_UI
              value: ' '
            - name: SERVICES
              value: 'sqs'
          image: localstack/localstack
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: localstack-main
          ports:
            - name: edge
              containerPort: 4566
              protocol: TCP
            - name: es
              containerPort: 4571
              protocol: TCP
            - name: ui
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 0
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: edge
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 0
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: edge
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/localstack
              name: localstack-claim0
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: localstack-account
      volumes:
        - name: localstack-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: localstack-claim0
status: {}
```

but when I start with kubectl apply -f path_To_yaml and wait until all services is started. I try to reach health check endpoint and I receive only exception that cannot connect to host

I try to use minikube tunnel , and this didn't help

May be some1 know how to configure right localy? I am novice in devops

try to use `minikube addons enable ingress` but didn't help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

try to manual expose and forward port with next command

```
kubectl expose pod localstack-deployment-7667b8d6bf-6mqbp --type=ClusterIP --name=localstack
```

and

```
kubectl port-forward po/localstack-deployment-7667b8d6bf-6mqbp 4566:4566
```

and connect with aws cli and awslocal cli; But the same result: could not connect

Comment: Hello @faceoff. Could you please check if you can `kubectl port-forward` to the pod directly?

Comment: I manually tried to use next command:
```
kubectl expose pod localstack-deployment-7667b8d6bf-6mqbp --type=ClusterIP --name=localstack
```

and 

```
kubectl port-forward po/localstack-deployment-7667b8d6bf-6mqbp 4566:4566
```

then try to connect with aws cli but always the same could not connect

Comment: Thanks @faceoff. I think your case needs some clarifications as it is kinda confusing now. You started with Minikube but now you also mentioned AWS CLI. Could you please explain what exactly you want to achieve and how?

Comment: i want to start localstack in minikube with right manifest; Localstack is local version of aws, so I try to reaching out localstack through aws cli

Comment: Did you try just using nodePorts? I'm about to make a deployment+service like this and use nodePorts on the service to keep it simple. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes clusters need to have an ingress controller for routing traffic from external world into

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

The above will enable ingress and you should see a valid ingress controller when you do a 'get pods

```
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-59868b7dd6-xb8tq       1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-addon-manager-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-dns-6dcb57bcc8-n4xd4                   3/3       Running   0          2m
kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-b8p5h       1/1       Running   0          2m
nginx-ingress-controller-5984b97644-rnkrg   1/1       Running   0          1m
storage-provisioner                         1/1       Running   0          2m
```

If this still does not solve your issue ,
please post additional information on below kubectl commands

```
kubectl describe ingress
kubectl describe service
```

The output of these commands might help assist you further

Comment: unfortunately didn't help
[![get pods -A][1]][1]

   [1]: https://imgur.com/7yjlqIs

[![describe ingress][2]][2]

   [2]: https://imgur.com/zjHwguw

[![describe service][3]][3]

   [3]: https://imgur.com/IKb6rsN

[![describe service part 2][4]][4]

   [4]: https://imgur.com/IbDYcEE

Comment: Did you notice that two of the pods in ingress-nginx are not in a READY state , until they turn to ready  , ingress service will not work , this explains why the describe ingress command returns none. Try to debug why the pods are not into READY